# Populate treeView from SQL Server Compact 3.5 database

Tags: c#, treeview, sql-server-ce

I'm recently trying to populate treeView from database. I've got two columns and two rows. My goal is to make treeView look like this (Order is not important right now) :

- Mercedes-Benz

  - 300SL
  - 500E
- BMW

  - M5
  - M6

My database looks like this:

[image]

I tried like this, but without luck

```
SqlCeCommand query = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY brand", con);
try
{
    SqlCeDataReader dr = query.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["model"].ToString());
        node.Nodes.Add(dr["brand"].ToString());

        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It's broken");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the parent node (brand) by its key and if it's not there, you add it to the root node list:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
  TreeNode[] brandNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find(dr["brand"].ToString(), false);
  if (!brandNode.Any()) {
    brandNode = new TreeNode[] { treeView1.Nodes.Add(dr["brand"].ToString(),
                                                     dr["brand"].ToString()) };
  }
  brandNode[0].Nodes.Add(dr["model"].ToString(), dr["model"].ToString());
}
```

The sort order can be handled by your SQL: `ORDER BY brand, model`

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I named this metod populateTreeview and called it inside "Add" button functon. It looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/2OGbVh6.png . Now everytime I click it to add records to db, every node in treeView duplicates, except latest http://i.imgur.com/qJEEzqx.png . Strange thing, because after restarting the program, everything looks fine http://i.imgur.com/MLKA6m6.png . My guess is that it's because I have 2 parent nodes, right?

Comment: @PotatoBox This method loads all of the nodes.  An Add button should only add one node, so it would be a different method.  That's a different question really, so if you need help with that, post that as a new question.